# Project Server - break connection between SP site and Project file?

Tags: project-server

When publishing Project files to Project Server, there is an option to create a related SharePoint site.

I have noticed that when deleting the Project file that was published, the SharePoint site will also be deleted.

Is there a way to create a related SP site on initial publish, but then break the connection so that if the Project file is deleted, the SP site is *not* deleted?

This is SP2016 on-prem.

---

As asked in the comments, the way I am deleting the files is through the `/_api/ProjectServer` REST endpoint.  So I guess that then begs the question - are there any kind of deletion options in REST that would instruct Project Server to delete the file but *not* the SharePoint site?

Comment: Hello @dylan, what do you mean with the project file! Is it the project plan.mpp? also, from where you are trying to delete it?

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP yes, I mean the `.mpp` file that gets saved to the server.  I am deleting the project file through the `/_api/ProjectServer` REST endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

Project Server and Project Online derive their basic information from the underlying project file. That file feeds the charts, the alerts, everything.   So deleting that file is like ripping out the roots of a tree and expecting the tree to still stand.

Comment: Well, to be clear, I don't expect any of my users to be using things like the linked task list, project summary, etc.  The main purpose of the SharePoint site in my scenario is to host a custom web part and custom list.  The site needs to live on even if the project file is deleted because any data saved to the custom list needs to be preserved.  So even if all of the intended functionality of a connected SP site breaks, my question still stands... is it possible to break the connection so that when a project file is deleted, the SP site remains?